# How to resampling a data series with date time indexing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

> 

### Resampling a data series with date time indexing in pandas

I am new to python and I am working on pandas. I have a GW2test.csv file containing date, time and other columns with data collected every 30 min. I need to resample the data for daily averages. 
The CVS looks like:

> 

```
Date        time     P    P3W   P3W1      P2W
04/18/12    15:00   0   1.334           1.006
04/18/12    15:30   0   1.336           1.003
04/18/12    16:00   0   1.323           0.985
04/18/12    16:30   0   1.316           0.977
04/18/12    17:00   0   1.312  1.231    0.97
```

P is precipitation and not always zero, P3W has some non measured values. 
What I did was:

`

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pylab as pl

df = pd.read_csv('GW2test.csv', parse_dates=[['Date','time']])

f = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=[ 'Date_time','P','P3E','P1W1', 'P1W', 'P2W'])

f.describe()

df1 = df.set_index('Date_time')

Daily= df1.resample('D', how=np**.mean)

Sel = Daily.ix[0:,['P']]

Sel.plot()

Sel = Daily.ix[0:,['P3W1']]

Sel.plot()
```

`

So far so good, my plots show dayly frequency in X, but the values in Y are wrong. Precipitation should be up to 140 and it goes only up to 3.5 (as 30 min values) and my P3W values are right but show a discontinuos line, although I have measurements for the entire period. They look like this

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not leave `Date` and `time` as separate columns, and then just perform a `groupby` on `Date` and aggregate each group using `np.mean`? This will produce a result indexed just by `Date` containing the average. And the same method could be used to group by `time` and take averages across dates, so you could easily see what the average is for all of the `15:00` observations, for instance.

```
df.groupby("Date").agg(np.mean)
```

The average of the `time` column can be ignored or that column can be left out.

Comment: If the question was able to address your needs, feel free to upvote or accept the answer.